# Show arguments in title/status bar of Emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to show Emacs command line arguments in status or title bar? Basically I start emacs like "emacs someproject/file.txt", and I want it to show "someproject/file.txt" somewhere in the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `command-line-args` variable may be sufficient, but non-file arguments which are processed by Emacs are also deleted from that variable, so it won't include those.

Try this:

```
(setq frame-title-format '(:eval (mapconcat 'identity (cdr command-line-args) " ")))
```

Answer (score 1):

The filename for the current buffer should be displayed in the modeline, which is what you should see if you're starting emacs with a file at the command line.  If that's not what you're seeing then you should provide more context so we can help you.  What configuration/customization have you done?  Maybe include a screenshot of what you *do* see.

Comment: modeline shows current buffer, but not the original command line arguments. The reason I want it is because I have one Emacs instance per project, with many buffers each, and want to tell them apart

Comment: If it shows the current buffer filename and the current buffer is what you supplied on the command line then what's missing.  *Please* elaborate and clarify if you want help.

Comment: I want to display command-line arguments, which stay the same across Emacs session

Comment: Ross: e.g. `--debug-init` or `--no-desktop`, along with any file arguments.

Comment: You might also want to look at `uniquify.el` which controls how the buffer name is generated.  The default `frame-title-format` might then be suitable for your needs (it displays the current buffer name; not sure if Windows supports this).